# onCompletionListener doesn't fire when screen is locked

Tags: android, locking

I am having some problems with the `setOnCompletionListener`.

When running on battery, if the screen is off, this method is not called. If I press the home screen, the method is instantly called.

For example, my song finishes while the screen is off / locked. The next song isn't called until I press a button and wake the screen up.

While plugged into the power / eclipse, this problem doesn't exist-- the songs transition seamlessly from one to the other.

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {            
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        startNextSong(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can use a wake lock for it depending on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your Player need to wokr on Service, because Activity or Fragment dies (Paused) when Screen locked.